# Compressing Double Values using C

Tags: c, compression, double, lz4

I have a data set of `double` values (1024 x 1024 matrix). I am thinking to use `lz4`compression algorithm to compress this data. After compressing, I have to send this data to a server and then doing some processing at the server side and get it back to the local machine. I am new to compression and little confuse.

Do i need to first put these `double` values in the file or some other format and then do compression or can i do compression directly on the values without putting them in the files or some other format.

Secondly, if you have any other recommendation beside `lz4` for compression then please do share.

Comment: What you compress is raw bytes, whether it is doubles or text or audio or whatever - it doesn't really matter. Different data tends to lend to compression differently.

Answer (score 3):

You can and would compress the doubles directly as a sequence of bytes, eight per double.  However you might not get much gain out of that.

What do you know about the data?  Is its range constrained?  Is its precision limited?  Are the values correlated to each other at all, e.g. are items in adjacent rows or adjacent columns, or both, likely to be close to each other or be close to linear progression or smooth curves?  Any information about the data would allow you to recode it to take less space and to preprocess it using predictors for better compression.

As for compressors, that is a trade-off between time and compression ratio.  For high speed but less compression, [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) is good.  For high compression but slower and a lot more memory, [lzma](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) is good.  For something in between, [zlib](http://zlib.net/) is good.

Independent of compression, you will also need to make sure that the server uses the same format for double.  It is extremely likely that both use the IEEE 754 format for a double, which nearly every machine does nowadays.  However you will need to check the endianess of the representation.  You may need to reverse the byte order of each eight-byte double in the stream if the machines have different endianess, i.e. one is little endian (e.g. Intel) and the other is big endian (e.g. Power PC or ARM).

Answer (score 2):

In general, whenever you're transmitting data between machines you should convert it into a standard format -- this is called *marshaling* or *serializing*. Otherwise, if the two machines have different representations for numbers, the data won't be interpreted correctly when it's received. However, if you know that the two machines use the same binary representation, you can just send the binary data itself.

Compression algorithms generally work on byte arrays or streams. But the address of a matrix of doubles can be cast to a `char(*)` before being passed to the compression function.

It's not clear how much benefit you'll gain from compressing doubles, though. Compression algorithms depend on finding common byte sequences and replacing them with shorter placeholders. Binary data may not have the kinds of redundancies that they depend on.

Answer (score 1):

Compression algorithms generally work on a sequence of bytes. They can compress from a file to a file, or from a block of memory to a block of memory if you like. Just link in somebody's compression library (like zlib or something else), and point it to your array of doubles--the library's compression function probably takes a `void *` argument and a `size_t` argument that will happily accept the address and size of your double array. It will neither know nor care that the memory contains doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Various compression algorithms like Lempel–Ziv are lossless.  The look for patterns in the original data and express the data, potentially, with less bytes.  Upon decompression, the entire exact origanl data is reconstituted.

Some compression methods are lossy like that used in .jpeg and .mpge files.

Compressing numeric data works just fine using lossless methods, like LZ.  Should your code desire greater compression, consider a simple conversion to `float`.  Of course `float` typically have reduced range and precision.  If these effects are tolerable, this lossy pre-compression to `float` will at least halve the original size and *may* offer a greater compression ratio.

Your compression does not need to involve first writing to a file.  Compression can be do within your code.

A cleaver method involves piping your data through a external process like `compress` or `uncompress`.